# Showing the existence of a linear transformation under conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $\mathbb{V}$ be a finite-dimensional inner product space over the field $\mathbb{F}$ (which can be $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), and let $T:\mathbb{V}\rightarrow \mathbb{V}$ be a self-adjoint linear transformation.

If we assume that $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$, how can I show that there exists a linear transformation $S:\mathbb{V}\rightarrow \mathbb{V}$ such that $S^2=T$?

I've only learned about one theorem in class which can show the existence of a linear transformation and it's the linear extension theorem, don't think I can apply it here. How should I proceed to solve this?

Comment: I think you can use here the Spectral Theorem for Self-Adjoint Operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the transformation $T$ is self-adjoint, it has real eigenvalues and a full set of (orthogonal) eigenvectors (this part is key). Let $S$ be *a* transformation defined by its eigenvalues being the square roots (the choice of signs is free) of $T$ and the corresponding eigenvectors are the same. Then $S^2=T$.

This is one of those fake-invariant proofs - fake, because it was discovered and formulated for matrices first and then artificially "lifted" to apply to more general vector spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So basically if I get it, by the Spectral Theorem we have an orthonormal basis {$\overrightarrow u_{1},...,\overrightarrow u_{n}$} for $T$ such that $T(\overrightarrow u_{1})=\lambda _{1} \overrightarrow u_{1}$ ... $T(\overrightarrow u_{n})=\lambda_{n} \overrightarrow u_{n}$. So basically we take $S(\overrightarrow u_{1})=\sqrt{\lambda_{1}}\overrightarrow u_{1}$...?